# Optimisation by CLR for separating expensive types by assemblies

Tags: .net

According to [an article on Codebetter](http://codebetter.com/blogs/patricksmacchia/archive/2008/12/08/advices-on-partitioning-code-through-net-assemblies.aspx), there is an optimisation by the CLR when separating assemblies so that code that is expensive but rarely used is only called once.

Is there any proof or any details on the extent of the optimisation?

Comment: @Patrick Smacchia very much knows what he is talking about, IMO - he's on SO so let's see if he can be summoned to this question...

Comment: Indeed. I am actually more interested in how much benefit I will get. I am definately sure there is some if he states so.